# Rolling back specific, older SQL transaction

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions, sql-server-2014

We have a fairly large stored proc that merges two people found in our system with similar names.  It deletes and updates on many different tables (about 10 or so, all very different tables).  It's all wrapped in a transaction and rolls back if it fails of course.  This may be a dumb question, but is it possible to somehow store and rollback just this specific transaction at a later time without having to create and insert into many "history" tables that keep track of exactly what happened?  I don't want to restore the whole database, just the results of a stored procedures specific transaction, and at a later date.

Comment: Note that I wouldn't want to restore the whole table either...just the records originally affected by the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may want to investigate [Change Data Capture](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/).

It will still be capturing data as it changes, and if you're only doing it for one execution or for a very small amount of data, other methods may be better.

Comment: Thanks, definitely going to read this.  It sounds like what I'm wanting to do at first glance, and never knew this was a feature...haha. :)

Answer (score 0):

Once a transaction has been committed, it's not possible to roll back just that one transaction at a later date.  You're "committed" in quite a literal sense.  You can obviously restore from a backup and roll back every transaction since a particular point, but that's probably not what you are looking for.

So making auditing tables are about your only option.  As another answer pointed out you can use Data Change Capture, but unless you have forked out the big money for Enterprise Edition, this isn't an option for you.  But if you're just interested in undoing this particular type of change, it's probably easiest to add some code to your procedure that does the merge to store the data records necessary to re-split them and create a procedure to do the actual split.  But you have to keep in mind that you must handle any changes to the "merged" data that might break your ability to perform the split.  This is why SQL can't do it for you automatically... it doesn't know how you might want to handle any changes to the data that might occur after your original transaction.

Comment: It appears I only have Standard Edition, so CDC won't work for me. It's not fun, but it does look like auditing tables are my only option at this point.  I'm considering making schema copies of each table being deleted/updated from to later undo changes...or a table that holds table, key, field, old/new values, and operation performed.  Either way, I learned about CDC and that it's only for Enterprise edition and Change Tracking, and how that won't work for me.